ayload CMS Form Block causing Jest worker errors in frontend, admin panel works fine
I'm experiencing an issue with Payload CMS where adding a form block causes Jest worker errors in the frontend, while the admin panel works fine. Here's my setup:
Environment:

Next.js (15.1.3)
Payload CMS
TypeScript

Current Configuration:
My form block configuration in payload.config.ts includes:
formBuilderPlugin({
  fields: {
    text: true,
    textarea: true,
    select: true,
    email: true,
    state: true,
    country: true,
    checkbox: true,
    number: true,
    message: true,
    payment: false,
  }
})

Problem:
Frontend throws error: "Jest worker encountered 2 child process exceptions, exceeding retry limit"
Admin panel works perfectly fine
Error occurs only when trying to render forms on the frontend
All API calls return 200 status codes
What I've tried:
Verified block registration in RenderBlocks.tsx
Checked version compatibility between packages
Confirmed proper block type matching in blockList.jsx
Question:
What could be causing the Jest worker errors specifically in the frontend while the admin panel functions normally? Are there any known issues with form block initialization in the frontend context?
